# Moving Object Interception / Projectile Collision

Tags: unity, physics, vector, collision-prediction

I am using Unity to attempt to have missile **A** launch at incoming missile **B** and blow it up.

However in order to do this accurately, **A** must be able to take into account **B**'s current velocity, direction and distance in order to calculate where it needs to aim in order to succesfully hit it.

How do we go about this using the below as an example?

[image: the_missile_problem]

Comment: Do these previous Q&A posts cover what you need? [Aim at moving target](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/74282/39518) / [How to calculate shot angle and velocity to hit a moving target?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/25277/39518) / [Calculate intersect point / aim point](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/97235/39518) / [Targeting system, vectors and angles maths](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/126549/39518) If not, try to edit your question to explain how you've tried applying the existing answers to your situation and where you've gotten stuck on an obstacle we can help with.